# Let's change "click here" link text on auto-login message to more meaningful link text

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Not *terribly* important, but a pet peeve of mine:

Whenever I come back to a stack-exchange site where my gmail associated account was logged in, but for one reason or another the stack-exchange site cookie was gone on that browser, the site dutifully logs me back in automatically (nice) and presents a message at the top that reads

```
Welcome back Faust, you've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page.
```

"Click here" is B-rate web design, and makes me cringe every time.

Also the link style is utterly un-distinguishable (at least on some sites, like Skeptics) from the regular text surrounding it.

w3c specifically recommends ever using it: [Don't say "click here"; not everyone will be clicking - Quality Web Tips](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)

**Can we please change this to:**

Welcome back Faust, you've been logged in. **Refresh the page.**

[with `text-decoration:underline` on the link, which I can't seem to effect in this posting]

Answer (score 3):

In the grand scheme of things it's really, *really* minor (which may be in and of itself a barrier to its implementation), but the change is harmless.

The thing is, the link is superfluous: you don't need to click on it to accomplish what it wants you to accomplish. Refreshing the browser using the browser's native refresh functionality works just as well. So it's purely for convenience, and changing it to:

> Welcome back Foo, you've been logged in. [Refresh the page](/#).

is still correct, even if there's a chance the user doesn't realize there's a link on "Refresh the page". If they follow what the message says and refreshed the page however way they know how, they accomplished the task the message prompted about.

So I say do it. Death to "click here to"!

Answer (score 1):

It is true, a link should generally not use *here*, or *click here* as text. In this case, as the link doesn't seem a link, in some sites, what would an average user understand with "Refresh the page"? If it would be evident in every Stack Exchange site that "Refresh the page" is a link, than "Refresh the page" would be better.
It is true there are other links on Stack Exchange sites that don't seem links until you don't hover the mouse over them, but those are a specific case, and we would not want to have *click here to vote to close the question* for *close*, and those links have a tooltip.

It would be better if the message were "Click on this message to refresh the page." In that case, though, the full message would cause the page refresh.

Comment: Click on what message? (*I* know what message, but does the user?) It's never smart to have one piece of text tell you to click on something else. For practical purposes it's a link. It just needs to be styled as all other links on the site to convey its click-ability. Just make the clickable thing tell them precisely and concisely what you get by clicking on it. This is a well-established convention. It's amateurish to have a "click here" anywhere on a site, and it's really easy to fix.

Comment: I didn't say it was fine to have _click here_. Consider that for any message you can give to users, there will be somebody who doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Another problem -- I've just realized -- for this meta site, Skeptics, and possibly other SE site designs, is that the link color is the *same* as the regular text color. That's bad.

Comment: That is what I was talking of, in the second sentence.